# How to implement ResourceUrlEncodingFilter with spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am working on application which is using spring 3.2.3.RELEASE and Spring Security 3.1.4.RELEASE. I want to implement static resource versioning in my application. I did implement this functionality with spring 4.3.11 with this reference http://www.baeldung.com/cachable-static-assets-with-spring-mvc i.e, working fine. Now when I am going to implement this with my old application i.e, not working.I am providing you the code snippet
In my web.xml

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>resourceUrlEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter
        </filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>resourceUrlEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
  <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

In spring.xml

```
<security:http auto-config="true" pattern="/**" use-expressions="true">
        <!-- Login pages -->
        <security:form-login login-page="/login" 
                             default-target-url="/home/" 
                             login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" 
                             authentication-failure-url="/login?error" />
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/home/"/>
        <!-- Security zones -->
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico" access="hasRole(ROLE_ANONYMOUS)" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_SUPER_USER')" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
      </security:http>
```

We are also using the caching filter in dispatcher servlet

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/resources/**" />
        <bean id="responseCachingFilter" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0" />
        <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true" />
        <property name="cacheMappings">
            <props>
            <prop key="/resources/**">21600</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
    </mvc:interceptor>
```

and the versioning code

```
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/")
                .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(6, TimeUnit.HOURS))
                .resourceChain(false)
                .addResolver(new VersionResourceResolver().addContentVersionStrategy("/**"))
                .addTransformer(new CssLinkResourceTransformer());
    }
```

but my versioning code is not working. Please suggest me where I need to change the code or other approach need to implement.

Thanks In advance

Comment: Thanks for rply.. I am getting following error: Following message HTTP Status 403 - Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found. and if I am disabling the the csrf <security:csrf disabled="true"> giving Incorrect UserName and Password error..

Comment: On jsp page, I am using : <form action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />" method='POST'>
                        <div>
                            <input id="username" type="text" name="j_username" placeholder="username"/>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <input type="password" name="j_password" placeholder="password"/>
                        </div>

Comment: On jsp page, I am using j_username and j_password as a parameter